# Script Exits When it Runs "Add-WindowsFeature"

Tags: forms, powershell

I have a script that i'm writing to add users to an exchange server, and check if RSAT is installed before proceeding, if its not then it presents you with a choice to install it.  The issue i'm having is that when you right click and click "run with powershell" or if you run the script from a command prompt, when you click yes on the prompt that asks to install it, then it just exits the script, with no output.  If i run the script from ISE, it installs with no issue.  I haven't seen that before so i'm a little lost, and googling I can't find a similar situation to this.

```
Import-Module ServerManager
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing


$ENDSCRIPT = $false
$CANCELCLICK = $null
$MODULECHOICE = $null
$NULLCHOICE = $null
$global:ISNULL = $null
<#$global:FirstName = $null
$global:LastName = $null
$global:Password = $null
$global:FullName = $null
$global:UPN = $null
$global:Alias = $null
$global:Company = $null#>

$global:FirstName = $textBox.Text
$global:LastName = $textBox1.Text
$global:Password = $textBox2.Text 
$global:FullName = $textBox3.Text
$global:UPN = $textBox4.Text
$global:Alias = $textBox5.Text
$global:Company = $listbox.SelectedItem


Function CREATEMAILBOX(){
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Mailbox Creation1'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,550)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,480)
$okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$okButton.Text = 'OK'
$okButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$okButton.Add_Click({DefineVars})
$form.AcceptButton = $okButton
$form.Controls.Add($okButton)

$cancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$cancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,480)
$cancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$cancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$cancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$cancelButton.Add_Click({CANCELCHECK})
$form.CancelButton = $cancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($cancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(480,20)
$label.Text = @"
Please enter the user's first name in the space below:
"@
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$global:textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$global:textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$global:textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox)

$label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,70)
$label1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(480,20)
$label1.Text = @"
Please enter the user's last name in the space below:
"@
$form.Controls.Add($label1)

$global:textBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$global:textBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,90)
$global:textBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox1)

$label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,120)
$label2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(480,20)
$label2.Text = @"
Please select the user's company from below:
"@
$form.Controls.Add($label2)

$global:listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$global:listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,140)
$global:listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$global:listBox.SelectionMode = 'One'

[void] $global:listBox.Items.Add('company1')
[void] $global:listBox.Items.Add('company2')

$global:listBox.Height = 40
$form.Controls.Add($listBox)

$label3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,180)
$label3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(380,30)
$label3.Text = @"
Please enter password to be assigned to the account.  Password must adhere to domain security policies:
"@
$form.Controls.Add($label3)

$global:textBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$global:textBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,210)
$global:textBox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox2)

$label4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,250)
$label4.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(380,20)
$label4.Text = @"
Please enter the user's full name below:
"@
$form.Controls.Add($label4)

$global:textBox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$global:textBox3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,270)
$global:textBox3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox3)

$label5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label5.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,300)
$label5.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(380,30)
$label5.Text = @"
Please enter the user's email address below.  This will be used for authentication from email clients, OWA, etc...:
"@
$form.Controls.Add($label5)

$global:textBox4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$global:textBox4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,330)
$global:textBox4.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox4)

$label6 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label6.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,370)
$label6.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(380,40)
$label6.Text = @"
Please enter the user's alias below, this is the "Pre-Windows 2000 Username" and can be used to logon to computers.  Follow company naming convention when specifying:
"@
$form.Controls.Add($label6)

$global:textBox5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$global:textBox5.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,410)
$global:textBox5.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox5)

$form.Topmost = $true

$form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})

$result = $form.ShowDialog()
}

function DefineVars(){
$global:FirstName = $textBox.Text
$global:LastName = $textBox1.Text
$global:Password = ConvertTo-SecureString $textBox2.Text -AsPlainText -Force
$global:FullName = $textBox3.Text
$global:UPN = $textBox4.Text
$global:Alias = $textBox5.Text
$global:Company = $listBox.SelectedItem
NullCheck2
}

function CheckRSAT(){
    if (!(Get-Module -listavailable "ActiveDirectory")){
    $MODULEBUTTONTYPE = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::YesNo
    $MODULEMESSAGETITLE = “RSAT Not Installed”
    $MODULEMESSAGEBODY = @"
RSAT AD Tools are not installed and are required to set company attribute on AD object.  

Would you like to install it now?  Choosing "No" will end script.
"@
    $MODULEICON = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Warning

    $global:MODULECHOICE = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($MODULEMESSAGEBODY,$MODULEMESSAGETITLE,$MODULEBUTTONTYPE,$MODULEICON)

    RSATChoice
    }
    else{
    CREATEMAILBOX
    }
}


function RSATChoice(){
    if ($MODULECHOICE -eq 'Yes')
    {
    Add-WindowsFeature -Name "RSAT-AD-PowerShell" –IncludeAllSubFeature -Verbose
    CheckRSAT
    }
    else
    {
        if ($MODULECHOICE -eq 'No'){
        return
        }
    }
}

function NullCheck2(){
if (!$FirstName -or !$LastName -or !$Password -or !$FullName -or !$UPN -or !$Alias -or !$Company){
$ISNULL = $true
NullCheck
}
    else{
    MailBoxCommandPrompt
    }
}

function NullCheck(){
if ($global:ISNULL = $true) {
$NULLBUTTONTYPE = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::YesNo
$NULLMESSAGETITLE = “Mailbox Creation”
$NULLMESSAGEBODY = "
You have not specified a value for one of the fields, please review them below for empty values


First Name: $FirstName
Last Name: $LastName
Password: $Password
Full Name: $FullName
UPN: $UPN
Alias: $Alias
Company: $Company

Would you like to try again?  Choosing No will end the script."
$NULLICON = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Warning

$NULLCHOICE = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($NULLMESSAGEBODY,$NULLMESSAGETITLE,$NULLBUTTONTYPE,$NULLICON)
    if ($NULLCHOICE -eq 'Yes'){
    CREATEMAILBOX
    }
        elseif ($NULLCHOICE -eq 'No'){
        return
        }
    }
}


Function MailBoxCommandPrompt(){
$BUTTONTYPE = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::YesNo
$MESSAGETITLE = “Mailbox Creation”
$MESSAGEBODY = "
Mailbox creation will proceed with the following commands.  

-->New-Mailbox -Name $FullName -UserPrincipalName $UPN -Password $Password -Alias $Alias -FirstName $FirstName -LastName $LastName -OrganizationalUnit domain.local/$Company
-->Set-User -Identity $Alias -Company $Company  

Do you wish to continue?  Choosing No will end the script.
"
$ICON = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Information

$CHOICE = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($MESSAGEBODY,$MESSAGETITLE,$BUTTONTYPE,$ICON)

if ( $CHOICE -eq 'Yes')
{
    New-Mailbox -Name "$FullName" -UserPrincipalName $UPN -Password $Password -Alias $Alias -FirstName $FirstName -LastName $LastName -OrganizationalUnit "domain.local/$Company"
    Set-User -Identity $Alias -Company $Company
}
    else
    {
    return
    }
}

function CANCELCHECK(){
return
}

CheckRSAT
```

EDIT:  Saw a typo in the RSATChoice function where it it was calling the createmailbox function after calling RSATChoice if the if statement was true, didn't really fix anything but i removed it for cleanliness.

Comment: In `CheckRSAT`, you set `$global:MODULECHOICE`, but when you try to check it in `RSATChoice`, you are missing the global scope: `$MODULECHOICE` - ah you got it lol

Comment: Yea i think i was answering and you were commenting at the same time.  Thanks though lol.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out.  When analyzing each step of the RSATChoice function I noticed that I had a local variable for $MODULECHOICE set as $null defined in the beginning of the script outside of a function and the value for this local variable was being displayed instead of the global one I had setup.  I changed it to $global:MODULECHOICE and that fixed the problem, i've put the working version below.

As a side note those reading this will notice the forms are different in the version i put below, this is because the one i was testing with only had two companies, the final will have 8 like the one below, i modified the forms only to add those extra companies.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn
Import-Module ServerManager
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing


$ENDSCRIPT = $false
$CANCELCLICK = $null
$global:MODULECHOICE = $null
$NULLCHOICE = $null
$global:ISNULL = $null
<#$global:FirstName = $null
$global:LastName = $null
$global:Password = $null
$global:FullName = $null
$global:UPN = $null
$global:Alias = $null
$global:Company = $null#>

$global:FirstName = $textBox.Text
$global:LastName = $textBox1.Text
$global:Password = $textBox2.Text 
$global:FullName = $textBox3.Text
$global:UPN = $textBox4.Text
$global:Alias = $textBox5.Text
$global:Company = $listbox.SelectedItem


Function CREATEMAILBOX(){
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Mailbox Creation'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,570)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,500)
$okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$okButton.Text = 'OK'
$okButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$okButton.Add_Click({DefineVars})
$form.AcceptButton = $okButton
$form.Controls.Add($okButton)

$cancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$cancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,500)
$cancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$cancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$cancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$cancelButton.Add_Click({CANCELCHECK})
$form.CancelButton = $cancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($cancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(480,20)
$label.Text = @"
Please enter the user's first name in the space below:
"@
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$global:textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$global:textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$global:textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox)

$label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,70)
$label1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(480,20)
$label1.Text = @"
Please enter the user's last name in the space below:
"@
$form.Controls.Add($label1)

$global:textBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$global:textBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,90)
$global:textBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox1)

$label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,120)
$label2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(480,20)
$label2.Text = @"
Please select the user's company from below:
"@
$form.Controls.Add($label2)

$global:listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$global:listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,140)
$global:listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$global:listBox.SelectionMode = 'One'

[void] $global:listBox.Items.Add('company1')
[void] $global:listBox.Items.Add('company2')
[void] $global:listbox.Items.Add('company3')
[void] $global:listbox.Items.Add('company4')
[void] $global:listbox.Items.Add('company5')
[void] $global:listbox.Items.Add('company6')
[void] $global:listbox.Items.Add('company7')
[void] $global:listbox.Items.Add('company8')


$global:listBox.Height = 100
$form.Controls.Add($listBox)

$label3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,240)
$label3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(380,30)
$label3.Text = @"
Please enter password to be assigned to the account.  Password must adhere to domain security policies:
"@
$form.Controls.Add($label3)

$global:textBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$global:textBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,270)
$global:textBox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox2)

$label4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,310)
$label4.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(380,20)
$label4.Text = @"
Please enter the user's full name below:
"@
$form.Controls.Add($label4)

$global:textBox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$global:textBox3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,330)
$global:textBox3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox3)

$label5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label5.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,360)
$label5.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(380,30)
$label5.Text = @"
Please enter the user's email address below.  This will be used for authentication from email clients, OWA, etc...:
"@
$form.Controls.Add($label5)

$global:textBox4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$global:textBox4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,390)
$global:textBox4.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox4)

$label6 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label6.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,430)
$label6.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(380,40)
$label6.Text = @"
Please enter the user's alias below, this is the "Pre-Windows 2000 Username" and can be used to logon to computers.  Follow company naming convention when specifying:
"@
$form.Controls.Add($label6)

$global:textBox5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$global:textBox5.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,470)
$global:textBox5.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox5)

$form.Topmost = $true

$form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})

$result = $form.ShowDialog()
}

function DefineVars(){
$global:FirstName = $textBox.Text
$global:LastName = $textBox1.Text
$global:Password = ConvertTo-SecureString $textBox2.Text -AsPlainText -Force
$global:FullName = $textBox3.Text
$global:UPN = $textBox4.Text
$global:Alias = $textBox5.Text
$global:Company = $listBox.SelectedItem
NullCheck2
}

function CheckRSAT(){
    if (!(Get-Module -listavailable "ActiveDirectory")){
    $MODULEBUTTONTYPE = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::YesNo
    $MODULEMESSAGETITLE = “RSAT Not Installed”
    $MODULEMESSAGEBODY = @"
RSAT AD Tools are not installed and are required to set company attribute on AD object.  

Would you like to install it now?  Choosing "No" will end script.
"@
    $MODULEICON = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Warning

    $global:MODULECHOICE = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($MODULEMESSAGEBODY,$MODULEMESSAGETITLE,$MODULEBUTTONTYPE,$MODULEICON)

    RSATChoice
    }
    else{
    CREATEMAILBOX
    }
}


function RSATChoice(){
    if ($MODULECHOICE -eq 'Yes')
    {
    Add-WindowsFeature -Name "RSAT-AD-PowerShell" –IncludeAllSubFeature -Verbose
    CheckRSAT
    }
    else
    {
        if ($MODULECHOICE -eq 'No'){
        return
        }
    }
}

function NullCheck2(){
if (!$FirstName -or !$LastName -or !$Password -or !$FullName -or !$UPN -or !$Alias -or !$Company){
$ISNULL = $true
NullCheck
}
    else{
    MailBoxCommandPrompt
    }
}

function NullCheck(){
if ($global:ISNULL = $true) {
$NULLBUTTONTYPE = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::YesNo
$NULLMESSAGETITLE = “Mailbox Creation”
$NULLMESSAGEBODY = "
You have not specified a value for one of the fields, please review them below for empty values


First Name: $FirstName
Last Name: $LastName
Password: $Password
Full Name: $FullName
UPN: $UPN
Alias: $Alias
Company: $Company

Would you like to try again?  Choosing No will end the script."
$NULLICON = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Warning

$NULLCHOICE = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($NULLMESSAGEBODY,$NULLMESSAGETITLE,$NULLBUTTONTYPE,$NULLICON)
    if ($NULLCHOICE -eq 'Yes'){
    CREATEMAILBOX
    }
        elseif ($NULLCHOICE -eq 'No'){
        return
        }
    }
}


Function MailBoxCommandPrompt(){
$BUTTONTYPE = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::YesNo
$MESSAGETITLE = “Mailbox Creation”
$MESSAGEBODY = "
Mailbox creation will proceed with the following commands.  

-->New-Mailbox -Name $FullName -UserPrincipalName $UPN -Password $Password -Alias $Alias -FirstName $FirstName -LastName $LastName -OrganizationalUnit domain.local/$Company
-->Set-User -Identity $Alias -Company $Company  

Do you wish to continue?  Choosing No will end the script.
"
$ICON = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Information

$CHOICE = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($MESSAGEBODY,$MESSAGETITLE,$BUTTONTYPE,$ICON)

if ( $CHOICE -eq 'Yes')
{
    New-Mailbox -Name "$FullName" -UserPrincipalName $UPN -Password $Password -Alias $Alias -FirstName $FirstName -LastName $LastName -OrganizationalUnit "domain.local/$Company"
    Set-User -Identity $Alias -Company $Company
}
    else
    {
    return
    }
}

function CANCELCHECK(){
return
}

CheckRSAT
```